# How to trim values from Angular form?

Tags: angular, spring, forms, rest

I have an Angular form with two inputs, username and password, when the user submits the form the values are sent with POST to a Spring Boot REST Controller.
I want to trim the datas before they are sent to the controller but I can't find how to do it.

This is my form-component.html:

```
    <form  #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" name="loginForm">
        <input required ngModel [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="loginUsername" #loginUsername="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="loginUsername.invalid && (loginUsername.dirty || loginUsername.touched)">Username not inserted</div>
        <input required ngModel [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="loginPassword" #loginPassword="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="loginPassword.invalid && (loginPassword.dirty || loginPassword.touched)">Password not inserted</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

This is my form-component.ts:

```
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit{

  user: User;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router, 
      private login: LoginService){
    this.user = new User();
  };

  ngOnInit(): void { };

  onSubmit() {
    this.login.send(this.user).subscribe(result => this.router.navigate(['/http://localhost:8080/login']));
  }

}
```

This is my user.ts:

```
export class User {

    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(){
        this.username = "";
        this.password = "";
    }
    
}
```

This is my login-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../classes/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  private loginUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/login';
   }

   public send(user: User) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.loginUrl, user);
  }
}
```

This is my Spring REST controller:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public void postUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("Username:" + user.getUsername());
        System.out.println("Password:" + user.getPassword());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
onSubmit() {
 this.user.userName = this.user.username.trim();
 this.user.password = this.user.passWord.trim();
 this.login.send(this.user).subscribe(result => 
 this.router.navigate(['/http://localhost:8080/login']));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use reactive forms to handle your form, it's much simpler to deal with forms.

It will look like this:

form-component.html:

```
<form  [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" name="loginForm">
        <input required name="loginUsername" type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="!formGroup.get('username').valid formGroup.get('username').touched)">Username not inserted</div>
        <input required name="loginPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="!formGroup.get('password').valid formGroup.get('password').touched)">Password not inserted</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

form-component.ts:

```
    import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
        export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit{
        
          user: User;
loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [TrimFormControl]),
    password: new FormControl('', [TrimFormControl]),
  });
        
          constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            private router: Router, 
              private login: LoginService){
            this.user = new User();
          };
        
          ngOnInit(): void { };
        
          onSubmit() {
            this.login.send(this.loginForm. getRawValue()).subscribe(result => this.router.navigate(['/http://localhost:8080/login']));
          }
        
        }
```

And then you can create a custom validator that trims automatically your inputs.

The custom validator:

```
export class TrimFormControl extends FormControl {
    private _value!: string | null;

    get value(): string | null {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: string | null) {
        this._value = value ? value.trim() : value;
    }
}
```

You put it in the array, on the form group creation above.
It's also a good practice to use reactive form in angular, it easier for you to handle verification in the form, and also very useful to use a same form, to create and update. (You can populate the input when you create the form group, the empty string mean that the inputs are empty).

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I have to add the TrimFormControl class? Because putting it in the form-component.ts gives me an error in the get value(), it says that is defined as a propriety in the class 'FormControl', but in this point is executed the override in in 'TrimFormControl' like a function of access ts(2611)

Comment: You can put in on a different class, create a typescript file and past it the custom validator, and it will work like a charm

Comment: @FilipeDoutelSilva Would this trim the values only for the validation? Or would the data be also trimmed when the form gets send to the server?

Comment: It will also trim values when you get it with .value. To answer the question yes the data will be trimmed when the form gets send to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I make a custom form validator that always returns null (no error).
Inside that validator I set the value for the input.

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export const trimValidator = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const value = control.value;

    if (!value || value === '') return null;

    if (value.startsWith(' ') || value.endsWith(' ')) {
        control.setValue(control.value?.trim(), { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
    }

    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Or through loop in submit function

```js
onSubmit() {
    const formValues = Object.values(this.loginForm.value)
      .map((val: unknown) => val as string)
      .map((val: string) => val.trim());

    this.login.send(formValues).subscribe(...);
}
```